# How to change the length of circular border

Tags: css

I am trying to make a level indicator for a website that I'm working on. I want it to show how close or far someone is from getting to the next level, i.e. show their points/xp in a nice circle graphic. So far this is what I have, but I can't seem to change the length of the loader/border.

I have searched everywhere and come up with nothing. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

```
.loader 
{
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: putAtStart .001s forwards;
}

@keyframes putAtStart 
{
    100% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good, easy to use solution. Its a javascript file that makes a nice and easily customizable progress bar.
https://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible by changing just one value using "border radius solution". To make the bar longer, You need to use another border to cover that and so on.

What You can do is to split it to 4 CSS classes for each quarter and apply them accordingly to current level.
To achieve any value of level indicator (and not just per 25%), You need to split loader div into 4 of them, each of them responsible for one quarter. Last div needs to have custom value of transforming (e.g. transform: rotate(15deg);). But there is more code (JS) needed. The biggest problem is to achieve the first 25% as rotating doesn't change the length.

```css
.loader 
{
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
}

.loader25
{
border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
animation: putAtStart 0.001s forwards;
}

.loader50 {
border-right: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
animation: putAtStart 0.001s forwards;
}

.loader75 {
border-bottom: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
animation: putAtStart 0.001s forwards;
}

@keyframes putAtStart {
100% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader loader25 loader50 loader75">test</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Here You have a JS solution I've mentioned on the beginning. Move the slider and see the smooth progress (click on the slider and use arrows to move it right/left):

```js
function progress() {
  var inputValue = $('input').val();

  var fixed = $('.loader-fixed');
  fixed.removeClass('loaded25');
  fixed.removeClass('loaded50');
  fixed.removeClass('loaded75');
  fixed.removeClass('loaded100');

  var rest = $('.loader-rest');
  rest.css('transform', 'rotate(' + (((inputValue * 360 ) / 100) - 45) + 'deg)');
  
  var cover = $('.loader-cover');

  if(inputValue >= 25) {
    cover.css('display', 'none');
    fixed.addClass('loaded25');
    if(inputValue >= 50) {
      fixed.addClass('loaded50');
      if(inputValue >= 75) {
        fixed.addClass('loaded75');
        if(inputValue >= 100) {
          /*
            This line be removed due to loader-rest 
            covers last quarter.
          */
          fixed.addClass('loaded100');
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    cover.css('display', 'block');
  }

}

progress();
```

```css
.loader {
  position: relative;
}

.loader-rest {
  border: 16px solid transparent; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Light grey */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.loader-fixed {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.loader-cover {
  border: 16px solid transparent; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.loaded25 {
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
}

.loaded50 {
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-right: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
}

.loaded75 {
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-right: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-bottom: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
}

/* This class can be removed. Check my comment in JS section */
.loaded100 {
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-right: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-bottom: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-left: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" onchange="progress()">
<div class="loader">
<!-- fixed is used for full quarters -->
<div class="loader-fixed"></div>

<!-- rest covers values between 0-25-50-75-100 -->
<div class="loader-rest"></div>

<!-- cover is used only when value is less than 25% so it hides part of the border -->
<div class="loader-cover"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try out this solution

Comment: After edit, the solution has one glitch: when the value is 0 to 25%, a blue artefact is visible top-left hiding behind the gray circle. Maybe it can be fixed somehow by setting background-color of 'loader-cover' to e.g. white (currently it will not work because it will cover everything in white).

Comment: I tried to use that and my own for quite some time, but nothing was working well. Eventually, I found progressbar.js which was a project that had all that I needed. Thanks so much for the hel[